# How to express a matrix where each row consists of replicas of element of a vector $x$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, matrix-decomposition

Let $x = \begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ \vdots \\ x_n \end{bmatrix}$

How do I find a way to express the following matrix

\begin{bmatrix} x_1 & x_1 & \ldots & x_1 \\ x_2 & x_2 &  \ldots & x_2 \\ \vdots  \\ x_n & x_n & \ldots & x_n\end{bmatrix}

into say a product between a matrix and vector $x$ (or an outer product, or hadamard product...etc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\begin{bmatrix}x_1 \\ x_2 \\ \vdots \\ x_n\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 & \cdots & 1\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Doh! Must be too tired

Comment: Same solution, but even more compact: $\vec{x}\vec{1}^T$.

Answer (score 1):

Your vector is an $n \times 1$ matrix, and the resultant matrix you want is $n \times n$. So, you would need a $1 \times n$ matrix.

Try $[1\quad 1 \quad \cdots \quad1]$